# How can I use an if statement to while reading from a file?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am almost brand new to programming. I am in my second college course. I have spent hours looking online and on here looking for help. I have to sort the salaries by year and add them together. I thought I could make an if statement to sort the salaries into different arrays, but it does not appear to be working. As you can see by the code output, it shows invalid year, but it also pops up that the year is 2014. The file that I am reading from follows this format:
2014 Employee Smith,John 2000 0 (this is one line and there are 9 more like it).
Thanks for any help and advice.

```
public class JohnSummersProject1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    String[] year = new String[10];
    String[][] employeeType = new String[10][2];
    String[][] name = new String [10][2];
    String[][] monthlySalary = new String [10][2];
    String[][] micellanious = new String[10][2];
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = " ";
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    String[] input = new String[5];
    String year2014 = "2014";


    try {
        String x = (args[0]);
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(x));
        while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null && line.length()!=0) {
            input = line.split(splitBy);
            year[count] = input[0];

            employeeType[count][0] = input[1];
            if(year[count] == year2014){
            name[count][0] = input[2];
            monthlySalary[count][0] = input[3];
            micellanious[count][0] = input[4];
            System.out.print(year[count] + " ");
            System.out.print(employeeType[count][0] + " ");
            System.out.print(name[count][0] + " ");
            System.out.print(monthlySalary[count][0] + " ");
            System.out.println(micellanious[count][0]);
            }
            else if(year[count] == "2015"){
            employeeType[count][1] = input[1];
            name[count][1] = input[2];
            monthlySalary[count][1] = input[3];
            micellanious[count][1] = input[4];
            System.out.print(year[count] + " ");
            System.out.print(employeeType[count][1] + " ");
            System.out.print(name[count][1] + " ");
            System.out.print(monthlySalary[count][1] + " ");
            System.out.println(micellanious[count][1]);
        }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid year");
            }
            count++;

        }
    } 
    catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("File IO exception" + io.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Issue closing the Files" + io.getMessage());
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <year.length; i++){
     System.out.println("Year " + year[i] + " Employee type = " +
       employeeType[i][0] + " Name: " + name[i] + " Monthly count = " +
             monthlySalary[i][0] + "extras: " + micellanious[i][0]);
    }
}
```

}
[It shows invalid year, but below it shows that the year is in fact 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1a5.png)

Comment: `year[count] == "2015"` is not how you compare `String`s in Java, use `String#equals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use method for comparing strings, you can't compare them using ==

Change

```
if(year[count] == "2015")
```

to

```
if(year[count].equalsIgnoreCase("2015"))
```

and other if statements based on this example